# C# .NET Windows Forms: highlighted checkbox not updating dataTable

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

I have a dataGridView with columns of boolean type (checkboxes), bound to a dataTable. I then use the values in the dataTable to send an API request somewhere at regular intervals. The issue is that when I click on a checkbox to change a value, it doesn't update the table right away. I have to click somewhere else before it gets updated. So say I check a box but keep the cell highlighted. Then, when the timer goes off, the program still thinks that the checkbox is unchecked. Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Comment: either leave comments on answers on what you are looking for or Accept an answer which solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
//set up the event handler.
dgv.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;

//Call CommitEdit only on CheckBoxCell
private void dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (dgv.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)   
    {      
        dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```